# drupal and paypal

Tags: drupal, paypal

How do I connect to paypal using drupal? which module should I use?

Answer (score 4):

[Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart)
This is full ecommerce module, enable there's paypal or paypal express.

[lm_paypal](http://drupal.org/project/lm_paypal)
This is support paid memberships (subscriptions), donations (tip jar) and paid adverts.

Answer (score 1):

Many modules interacts with paypal.
The question is, what are you trying to achieve?

If you look at [www.drupalmodules.com](http://www.drupalmodules.com) and searches for paypal, you get several modules back.
Some of the options are, Donation, charge creation of specific nodes, and lots of other options.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [Angell EYE PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/overview-of-php-class-library-for-paypal/).

It's an object oriented library and should be pretty simple to plug into Drupal.  It includes nearly everything PayPal provides (ie. Payments Pro, PayFlow, Express Checkout, Adaptive Payments, Adaptive Accounts, everything in the PayPal NVP documentation, and more.)

I did convert it to a CodeIgniter library without much trouble at all and have had plans to do the same for Joomla, Drupal, Zend, etc.  Just haven't had time to do it yet, but again, you should be able to make it work with Drupal pretty easily.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13337423)

Comment: I adjusted the answer to specifically name the library, and I've left the link for reference purposes.